# Json Result isn't working when I use db.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Modified;

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, crud, notify

I Have a view where I can edit and add new Rows on my SQL called by AddOrEdit. All I need is to press the button Submit after fill/change the fields. It calls my ActionResult on *AccountController* that brings me a JsonResult and my AJAX function on button click get the JsonResult to fill a Notify.js message to say that the submit was successfully done.

Problem:
When I create a new row, all works how should be but when I update a existing row, the Success message comes to my browser as raw Json.

**Controller:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddOrEdit(UserPortal user)
        {
            using (ModelEntities db = new ModelEntities())
            {

                try
                {

                    if (user.UserID == 0)
                    {
                        db.UserPortals.Add(user);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Submitted Successfully. Redirecting..." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(new { success = true, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

        }
```

**View:**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)" }))
{
<form id="AddOrEditUserForm">

                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserEmail)
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserCompany, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserCompany, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserCompany)
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPosition, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPosition, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserAccessLevel, new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserAccessLevel, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserAccessLevel)
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
}
```

**Javascript on View:**

```js
function SubmitForm(form) {

                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

                if ($(form).valid()) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: form.action,
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function (data) {

                            var delay = 2000; // time in milliseconds
                            if (data.success) {


                                $.notify(data.message, {
                                    globalPosition: "top center",
                                    className: "success",
                                })

                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("AdminUsers", "Account")'; //redirect to the main page after some seconds
                                }, delay);

                            }

                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { errorFunction(); },
                    });

                }
                    return false;

            }
```

**Notify.js working when I add a new user:**
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O86Ms.png)
**When I click on submit button to update a existing user**
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USL9.png)

What I've tried:

1- I add some console.log on my Submit Function and after `if ($(form).valid())` I just don't receive anymore my console.log test. I think the problem is the Function and the ajax inside it.

2- On controller I gave a single JsonResult for each situation: to create I had a message saying "Created Successfully" and It worked but on the message below "Update Successfully" I got the same problem: a raw json on my screen but working perfectly on backend updating the row I requested.